# Can AjaxMinTask output a single file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

I have multiple js input files. How can I make the Microsoft Ajax Minifier (using AjaxMinTask.dll) combine them into a single minified js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
<Exec Command="echo y| type %(SourceFiles.Identity) &gt;&gt; $(ScriptOutputPath)\$(RootNamespace).debug.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the JsSourceExtensionPattern/JsTargetExtension pair, use the JsCombinedFileName property (and the corresponding equivalents for CSS). If the JsCombinedFileName property is set, it will combine all the input JS files into the path specified by the property, rather than minifying each file separately.